# How to change background color of days before today in FullCalendar...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to change the background color of Days in my [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar)

How can i do this..?

Answer (score 10):

Each day has a class, so you could add the following to your style sheet:

```
.fc-sun{background-color:Red;}
.fc-mon{background-color:green;}
.fc-tue{background-color:blue;}
```

> How can this be used to identify days before today?

You'll need to use some jQuery:

```
$('.fc-today').prevAll('td').css('backgroundColor','yellow');
$('.fc-today').parent().prevAll().find('td').css('backgroundColor','yellow');
```

Comment: How can this be used to identify days before today?

Comment: @AlexThomas i tried this but the problem i am getting is that once the background is changed, it remains the same for all the next months and the previous months whereas it should be like the previous moths should have this background on all days and the next shouldn't have it on any days. Can we do that somehow, or am i doing some thing wrong? i am a beginner so bear with me if its a very stupid question.

Comment: ok i solved it by adding it to the viewDisplay callback, sorry stupid mistake :)

Comment: Hi its changing the background color current date row and row previous to current date. but my requirement is for Eg.
if today is 7/01/2013 then all previous dates should have a background yellow for any previous month or date. please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks! for me 'background' worked instead of 'backgroundColor''

Answer (score 2):

OPTION 1
there is class in each cell

```
.fc-past
.fc-today
.fc-future
```

You can use them in your css and make some colors for past, today and future.

OPTION 2
You can loop for each day cell and do some check's
Here is example with month view

```
$('.fc-day').each(function(){
    if($(this).is('.fc-today')) return false;
    $(this).addClass('fc-before-today');
})
```

CSS

```
.fc-before-today{background-color:red}
```

Comment: use of .fc-past is, by far, the best solution nowadays

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (a bit verbose, but you can shorten it as much as you like):

```
var today = $('.fc-today');
var classNames = today.attr('class');
var index = classNames.indexOf('fc-day') + 6;
var day;

if (index > 0) {
    day = classNames.substr(index, 2);

    for (day = day-1; day >= 0; day -= 1) {
        $('.fc-day'+day).addClass('fc-before-today');
    }
}
```

Have a look at it on **JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4nuQ/**

Also, I'm sure you could use a regular expression selection filter with jQuery, but why bother? It's never going to be more than 42* elements, so performance isn't such an issue.

** Really! Six weeks, seven days a week: `6 × 7 = 42`. :-)*

Comment: @AlexThomas: probably, but "there's no kill like overkill". Your solution is certainly a lot shorter. I suggested this approach, because it explicitly selects on the `fc-dayXX` class. The calendar will probably never contain a `td` that *does't* have this class, but still... I like to be safe rather than sorry. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var d=new Date();
var dat=d.getDate();


$('tbody tr').find('.fc-day-number').each(function(){

if($(this).val() == dat)
 {
     $(this).parents('div').siblings().prevAll().css('background-color','red');               
     return false;
 }

});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this loop be executed for each of the days, not just the current one? This would mean the css property is set `n` times for the first sibling, `n-1` times for the second, and so forth...  Also: is there a reason why you use `Date` instead of selecting on `.fc-today`?

Answer (score 0):

Do it in css, as simple as

```
.fc-past {
  background-color: #F5F5F6
}
```